# With Scala 2.10.2, SBT 0.13.0, Specs2 & Play Framework 2.2.1 how can I control logging whilst running tests?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm getting mightily confused about the different logging frameworks being used by our Play 2 framework Scala application - and even with trial and error I've not found a way to provide a separate logging configuration file between running the application using 'run' and 'test'.

Our application is using `play.api.Logger` instances to output logs. We've got various other play plugins that seem to be outputting directly via logback.

So far we've been controlling log output successfully using a single `conf/logger.xml` (this is the logback configuration right?) file. This sets up two appenders with patterns and controls the output levels. When executing the app through `'run'` absolutely no issues.

If I try and provide an alternative `conf/logger-test.xml` file - running with `'test'` ignores it. I've tried doing:

```
testOptions in Test ++= Seq(
        Tests.Setup(() => {
            println("Setting logger to logger-test.xml")
            System.setProperty("logger.file", "conf/logger-test.xml")
        })
    ),
```

In `Build.scala` but that does not affect anything.

So, in an effort to understand the different components in use, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger seems to indicate that a) play actually is using a seperate logging framework internally and b) then pushes that to logback. What I have no idea about is how to tell which of those implementations is broken.

Can anyone help me understand how play 2 logging works in this respect and through that help me fix my particular issue? From some googling it looks as if there might be problems with play with logging configuration when using `'dist'` as well but I'm not there yet.

## EDIT:

I'm wondering if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341614/how-to-configure-logging-in-play-framework-2-0-for-junit-tests) is the issue? Not had chance to try it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember struggling with the same issue. Basically, when running tests I couldn't find a way to have Play! use a different logger configuration. I ended up finding a way: I have `conf/logger.xml` for my production code and I added `/test/resources/logger-text.xml` to configure my logger when running tests.

My log configuration files follow the logback syntax for configuration. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, should that be `test/resources/logger-test.xml`? Does that require any further configuration to work or is it a by-convention thing? Any pointers to documentation on that mechanism? I'm trying to understand how all of this works so I can help myself in the future :)

Comment: It seems that it is a convention thing since I did not change anything else. I didn't any documentation about it, just tried and it worked :) I guess that a configuration located in `test/resources/` takes precedence over what is in `conf`.

Comment: I've started using Play 2.5 and this didn't work for me. I wonder if it doesn't work anymore. I was able to add `.settings(javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.file=test/resources/logback-test.xml")` to my build config and that worked though.